# How to install/update to sympy 1.4 under in Latest Anancoda 2019.03?

Tags: anaconda, sympy

**Update**

Thanks for the hint by @cel below, the command to use is

```
>sudo conda install sympy=1.4

## Package Plan ##
  environment location: /opt/anaconda

  added / updated specs:
    - sympy=1.4

The following packages will be downloaded:
    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    sympy-1.4                  |           py37_0         9.7 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         9.7 MB
The following packages will be REMOVED:

  anaconda-2019.03-py37_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  sympy                                          1.3-py37_0 --> 1.4-py37_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

Verified OK after installation:

```
>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.__version__
'1.4'
>>>
```

I have no idea why other commands did not work. But the above works.

---

**Original question**
I am using Linux Manjaro 64 bit. Installed latest Anancoda

```
>which python
/opt/anaconda/bin/python

>conda list anaconda
# packages in environment at /opt/anaconda:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda                  2019.03                  py37_0  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py37_0
```

The problem is that it comes with sympy 1.3, while latest sympy is 1.4 accoding to

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/releases

sympy 1.4 has been out 3 weeks ago.

Now doing

```
  >sudo conda update sympy
```

Does not update. It says

```
## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /opt/anaconda

  added / updated specs:
    - sympy


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    ca-certificates-2019.1.23  |                0         126 KB
    certifi-2019.3.9           |           py37_0         155 KB
    conda-4.6.14               |           py37_0         2.1 MB
    openssl-1.1.1b             |       h7b6447c_1         4.0 MB
    sympy-1.3                  |           py37_0         9.5 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        15.9 MB
```

But according to https://anaconda.org/anaconda/sympy  it says sympy 1.4 is available

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also tried the command above, and it does not update sympy

```
>sudo conda install -c anaconda sympy

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /opt/anaconda

  added / updated specs:
    - sympy


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    ca-certificates-2019.1.23  |                0         126 KB  anaconda
    certifi-2019.3.9           |           py37_0         155 KB  anaconda
    conda-4.6.14               |           py37_0         2.1 MB  anaconda
    openssl-1.1.1b             |       h7b6447c_1         4.0 MB  anaconda
    sympy-1.3                  |           py37_0         9.5 MB  anaconda
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        15.9 MB
```

Any one knows why sympy is not being updated? Anything else to try? I could download the tar file from sympy 1.4, but I do not know what to do after that in order to install it in Anancoda.

Comment: It looks like some package in your environment might be blocking the installation. You could try `conda install sympy=1.4` and  see if you get a useful error message why it doesn't want to install it

Comment: @cel great! that worked. Please feel free to post this as answer and I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When conda update does not want to update a package, you can ask conda explicity to install a specific version: `conda install sympy=1.4`.